# Testing wether column values is =0, Then

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the below code to check if a column is empty, and if it is, it should be deleted, but it gives me a Range Error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Hide()


   If Range(E3, E1549) = "" Then

      Columns("E:E").Hidden = True

      End If

      End Sub
```

Comment: the `Dim Sominha As String` shouldn't be there, can anyone edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the test you would perform in the worksheet:

```
Sub Hide()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("E3:E1549")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r) = r.Count Then
        Columns("E:E").Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

*COUNTBLANK() counts empty cells, cells containing NULL, and cells containing formulas returning NULL.*

Comment: I'm trying to modify this code to use it with a loop, why doesn't the following work?:
`Sub Hide()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim col As Range
    
    l = 3

    Set r = Range("E3:E1549")
    Set col = Columns("l")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r) = r.Count Then
        col.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `Range` error because your range reference is incorrectly formed. And you can't check an entire `Range` against a single value unless you create a loop. You can make the check with a worksheet function:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E:E")) = 0 Then 
    Debug.Print "Column is empty" 
Else 
    Debug.Print "Column is not empty" 
End If
```

Comment: The thing is that if I create a loop it will take ages to finish, as the sheet is huge. Is it possible, then, to check if the sum of that column = 0, `Then Columns("E:E").Hidden = True`?

Comment: Take a look at the `CountA` [documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/counta.php). This function will tell you if the cells in the range are empty -- if the range is empty, the the function returns zero (because there are zero non-blank cells in the range). Then yes, you can hide column E if you like based on that result.